# SAP Runtime error when showing Multiple parents of an entity using CDS hierarchy in the SAPUI5 Tree table

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, smart-table, treetable, cds

I'm using **CDS parent child hierarchy** to get multiple parents of an entity.

There is no problem with the data that has a single parent.

But when I try to display the data that has multiple parents, it's dumping. There is no dump when I get the multiple parent data from the CDS hierarchy using SE38 report.

I have already specified *Multiple parents allowed* in the CDS hierarchy

I'm getting the following error text

> ***Hierarchy error: The hierarchy source data contains node 00012345 having multiple parents but the hierarchy is specified to reject such nodes.: line 1 col 821 (at pos 820)***
>
> [image]

Comment: It's a backend error, not frontend. The only needed tag is [tag:cds], all others are superfluous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

We need to redefine the CDS hierarchy class method (defined in @ObjectModel.query.implementedBy) IS_READ_ONLY_MULTI_PARENT_HIER to set the indicator as 'X' to support the Multiple parent scenario.

It is not supported by default.

Answer (score 0):

`MULTIPLE PARENTS NOT ALLOWED` is the CDS Hierarchy default behavior. You need to fix your CDS Hierarchy, see [ABAP documentation - DEFINE HIERARCHY](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_cp_index_htm/CLOUD/en-US/abencds_f1_define_hierarchy.htm#!ABAP_ADDITION_10@10@):

> Addition 10
>
> `... MULTIPLE PARENTS {NOT ALLOWED}|{LEAVES ONLY}|ALLOWED`
>
> The optional addition MULTIPLE PARENTS specifies whether the hierarchy can have child nodes with multiple parent nodes:
>
> `NOT ALLOWED`
>
> - This is the **default** setting (a child node can have exactly one parent node only).
>
> `LEAVES ONLY`
>
> - Only leaf nodes can have multiple parent nodes.
>
> `ALLOWED`
>
> - All hierarchy nodes can have multiple parent nodes.

Comment: I have already included MULTIPLE PARENTS ALLOWED in the CDS hierarchy view to have multiple parents. And I'm able to get the data in the backend from the query SELECT * FROM HIERARCHY_ANCESTORS.... Only while I'm showing it in the app, it's dumping with that error message